# BeautifulSoup return empty using find_all("span", text = re.compile("T"))

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The html file can be download from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15562376/test.html)

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(r"test.html"),from_encoding="ascii")
In [43]:soup.find_all("span")
Out[43]:
    [<span style="position:absolute; border: gray 1px solid; left:0px; top:50px; width:648px; height:783px;"></span>,
     <span style="font-family: LJOGFN+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd; font-size:7px">S
     <br/></span>,
     <span style="font-family: LJOGFN+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd; font-size:7px">T
     <br/></span>,
     <span style="font-family: LJOGFN+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd; font-size:8px">N
     <br/></span>,
     <span style="font-family: LJOGFN+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd; font-size:7px">E
     <br/></span>,
     <span style="font-family: LJOGFN+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd; font-size:7px">T
     <br/></span>,
     <span style="font-family: LJOGFN+HelveticaNeueLTStd-Bd; font-size:8px">N
     <br/></span>]

 In [44]:soup.find_all("span", text = re.compile("T"))
 Out[44]:[]
```

Why does it return empty list?  Is this related to encoding?

Update: The following code works:

```
In [87]: 
def aa(tag):
    return tag.name == "span" and re.match("T", tag.text)
In [88]:soup.find_all(aa)[0]
```

How is it working this way?

Comment: you could do like this `[i for i in s.findAll('span') if i.text == 'N']`

Comment: @AvinashRaj it does not work, I just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument), your code should work. You should file a bug report.

EDIT: It looks like this problem is caused by `<br>` tags in the `<span>` elements. This is definitely a bug.

To work this around, use a lambda so that you don't need to define a function:

```
soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == "span" and re.match("T", tag.text))
```